# IndexError: string index out of range errors

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk

I run my nltk python program on another computer and it works fine, but on my computer I'm getting these errors:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/Text Mining/Text mining-20161123T063352Z/Text mining/SentAnal/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 151, in <module>
    analyze()
  File "D:/Text Mining/Text mining-20161123T063352Z/Text mining/SentAnal/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 135, in analyze
    negativeFeatures, positiveFeatures = process_categories()
  File "D:/Text Mining/Text mining-20161123T063352Z/Text mining/SentAnal/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 119, in process_categories
    words = stem_words(words)
  File "D:/Text Mining/Text mining-20161123T063352Z/Text mining/SentAnal/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 37, in stem_words
    words2.append(porter.stem(word))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\porter.py", line 665, in stem
    stem = self._step1b(stem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\porter.py", line 376, in _step1b
    lambda stem: (self._measure(stem) == 1 and
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\porter.py", line 258, in _apply_rule_list
    if suffix == '*d' and self._ends_double_consonant(word):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\porter.py", line 214, in _ends_double_consonant
    word[-1] == word[-2] and
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

On both computers I am using  Python 2.7.13 and Pycharm Community Edition.

What could be the cause? thanks!

Comment: Pretty clear from the error. `word[-1] == word[-2]` The variable `world` has less than 2 elements.

Comment: i dont know what exactly word is but it sounds that word has only one character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you are processing is different on the two machines. There is probably a word in the data set which has only one letter on your machine.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thanks!